# In PyCharm's Data sources unable to connect to sqlite3 databases

Tags: sqlite, database-connection, database-schema, pycharm

In my PyCharm (2.0 Beta 2) on my Windows 7 machine, however I am not able to load the contents and schema of sqlite3 databases.

I downloaded to a directory both the two sqlite drivers: sqlitejdbc-v056.jar from Zentus and to be on the safe side the one from Xerial sqlitejdbc-3.7.2.

- The JDBC driver class is set to org.sqlite.JDBC
- The database URL is
  set to: jbdc:sqlite:c:/Users/Myself/path/to/db.db
- No username or
  password.

When I hit "Test Connection" all is well and "Connection Successful" and when I hit Refresh Schema it says "0 tables available".

I guess that the fault is: loading the JDBC driver from disk or the URL but both would expected to be mitigated by the "Connection Succesful" statement.

The database is loadable and has contents in my Mozilla Firefox SQLite Manager Extension.

idea.log output:

**Zentus**:

```
2011-12-07 14:06:14,367 [ 783461]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\pycharm 111.33\jre\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\plugins\DatabaseSupport\lib\jdbc-console.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\lib\annotations.jar;C:\SENSORED\shared-development\jdbc-drivers-pycharm\sqlitejdbc-v056.jar" com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer org.sqlite.JDBC 
2011-12-07 14:06:14,537 [ 783631]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID:8205/RemoteDriverImplfd8de8cc 
2011-12-07 14:06:14,720 [ 783814]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code 1 `
```

**Xerial**:

```
2011-12-07 14:02:19,768 [ 548862]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\pycharm 111.33\jre\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\plugins\DatabaseSupport\lib\jdbc-console.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\lib\annotations.jar;C:\SENSORED\shared-development\jdbc-drivers-pycharm\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer org.sqlite.JDBC 
2011-12-07 14:02:19,967 [ 549061]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID:47142/RemoteDriverImpl2975ea52 
2011-12-07 14:02:20,445 [ 549539]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code 1 
2011-12-07 14:02:22,823 [ 551917]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\pycharm 111.33\jre\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\plugins\DatabaseSupport\lib\jdbc-console.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 111.33\lib\annotations.jar;C:\SENSORED\shared-development\jdbc-drivers-pycharm\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer org.sqlite.JDBC 
2011-12-07 14:02:23,006 [ 552100]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID:37172/RemoteDriverImpl304666a8 
2011-12-07 14:02:23,305 [ 552399]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code 1`
```

Comment: Does it happen with both drivers? We have an issue logged for the Xerial driver at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-78339 which looks similar. Can you check `idea.log` for exceptions?

Comment: I added the idea.log when calling the drivers and the database. Checking both the 'connection' as well as the 'refresh schema'. Possibly I will add this to the issue IDEA-78339.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-78080) in the beta which is already fixed. The fix should be available in the next build (the linked bug is reported for SQL Server, but the problem also affected SQLite).

Comment: I've been searching after you comment, but did not come across it probably because of the SQL server angle on the bug. Thanks. We'll live with it for now.